# Loading multiple GeoJSONs, how to use different markers/pop-ups for each

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I spent all day trying to figure out how to load more than one GeoJSON. Finally figured it out thanks to an earlier SE question. Now I'm stuck trying to symbolize each GeoJSON

I would like to symbolize each GeoJSON differently, of course, but I'm really at a loss as to where to go next. The old code (at the bottom) worked fine on a single layer, but I don't know how to modify it for the individual geojsons.

I hope my code isn't too bad or unreadable!

```js
//blahblahblah, initial headers, etc

//load breweries GeoJSONs from external file
var breweries = new L.geoJson();
breweries.addTo(map);

$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "breweries.geojson",
    success: function(data) {
        $(data.features).each(function(key, data) {
            breweries.addData(data);
        });
    }
}).error(function() {});

//load wineries GeoJSON from external file
var wineries = new L.geoJson();
wineries.addTo(map);

$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "winetest.geojson",
    success: function(data) {
        $(data.features).each(function(key, data) {
            wineries.addData(data);
        });
    }
}).error(function() {});


//skip this intermediate stuff


//load Brewery GeoJSON from an external file
$.getJSON("breweries.geojson", function(data) {
    var pintGlass = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'glass.png',
        iconSize: [24, 48]
    });

    var popupMarker = L.geoJson(data, {
        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
            var marker = L.marker(latlng, {
                icon: pintGlass
            });
            //popup shows NAME, ADDRESS, URL and opens the URL in a new window/tab
            marker.bindPopup("<strong>" + feature.properties.NAME + "</strong><br/>" + feature.properties.STREETNUM + " " + feature.properties.STREET + ", " + feature.properties.CITY + "<br/>" + "<a target = _blank href=" +
                feature.properties.URL + ">" + feature.properties.URLDISPLAY + "</a>");
            return marker;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code is readable, but your question is unclear. Which aspects of the symbology you want to change? Do you just want to use a different icon for wineries vs. breweries, or is it more complex than that? We will have a better idea of how to help you if you can give more detail about: (1) what you want your program to do; and (2) what it is currently doing that's wrong.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that.
I want to have a different symbol for breweries (say, a pint glass) and a different symbol for wineries (say, grapes). Both will need popups displaying name, address, URL, etc. 

I also want users to be able to turn off the breweries or wineries layer, or show them both. Though, I have figured this part out already, I think.

In addition, I am hoping to incorporate the cluster plugin with all of these layers.

I hope that helps clear things up! Thanks!

Comment: In the end, I want to: 1) Have a different symbol for each feature (breweries, wineries, etc). 2) Be able to turn off each feature type or have them all on, the map user's choice. 

It seems like the best way to do this, is to have multiple geojsons, but if I could drive this all from a single geojson and just use the attributes, that would be just fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can move the `pintGlass` icon definition outside of the `$.getJSON` callback function, since it doesn't depend on the value of the returned data:

```js
var pintGlass = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'glass.png',
  iconSize: [24, 48]
});
```

Then, if you want to access your `L.geoJson` layer outside the `$.getJSON` callback function (for instance, if you are going to refer to it when building a layer control later), you will also need to define that first outside of `$.getJSON`. You can actually create an empty `L.geoJson` object by passing it a `false` as its first parameter, while still setting the options, which will be applied to any data you add to it later:

```js
var popupMarker = L.geoJson(false, {
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        var marker = L.marker(latlng, {
            icon: pintGlass
        });
        //popup shows NAME, ADDRESS, URL and opens the URL in a new window/tab
        marker.bindPopup("<strong>" + feature.properties.NAME + "</strong><br/>" + feature.properties.STREETNUM + " " + feature.properties.STREET + ", " + feature.properties.CITY + "<br/>" + "<a target = _blank href=" +
            feature.properties.URL + ">" + feature.properties.URLDISPLAY + "</a>");
        return marker;
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Then, your `$.getJSON` function won't have to do anything but add the data to your layer:

```js
$.getJSON("breweries.geojson", function(data) {
    popupMarker.addData(data);
});
```

Now it should be relatively simple to copy and modify this code to handle wineries. Assuming you have an icon called `grapes.png`, it would look like this:

```js
var wineIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'grapes.png',
  iconSize: [32, 32]
});

var wineMarker = L.geoJson(false, {
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    var marker = L.marker(latlng, {
      icon: wineIcon
    });
    //popup shows NAME, ADDRESS, URL and opens the URL in a new window/tab
    marker.bindPopup("<strong>" + feature.properties.NAME + "</strong><br/>" + feature.properties.STREETNUM + " " + feature.properties.STREET + ", " + feature.properties.CITY + "<br/>" + "<a target = _blank href=" +
      feature.properties.URL + ">" + feature.properties.URLDISPLAY + "</a>");
    return marker;
  }
}).addTo(map);

$.getJSON("winetest.geojson", function(data) {
  wineMarker.addData(data);
});
```

As for the layer controls, that is a separate question, but one that should be easy enough to answer by looking at the [layer control tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html).

Here is an example fiddle with some dummy data showing everything at work:

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/tuppLt0b/

And another example, in which the `L.geoJson` has `pointToLayer` and `onEachFeature` broken out into separate functions:

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/Lo8cmuvt/

(Incidentally, the `$.ajax` routine at the beginning of your code is redundant, since `$.getJSON` is a shorthand method that does the exact same thing.)

Comment: I just came down with a nasty cold, so it might be a day or two before I get to tinkering. I'm pretty sure I owe you a tasty beer or coffee though, this looks like exactly the kind of response I need. Wow, thank you so much nathansnider!!